What did Nietzsche mean by “a word is the copy in sound of a nerve stimulus”?
In On Truth and Lies in a Nonmoral Sense, Nietzsche wrote (my emphasis):

If he will not be satisfied with truth in the form of tautology, that is to say, if he will not be content with empty husks, then he will always exchange truths for illusions. What is a word? It is the copy in sound of a nerve stimulus. But the further inference from the nerve stimulus to a cause outside of us is already the result of a false and unjustifiable application of the principle of sufficient reason.

This definition of ‘word’ caught my attention because it feels somewhat reductive. As a philologist, Nietzsche would have been aware of other ways to define a word. For instance, Saussure pointed out that a word like the French nu (“naked”) can be understood in different ways depending on the perspective—whether as a sound, an idea, or a derivative of the Latin nūdum.
Why, then, does Nietzsche focus on this particular definition? What did he mean? Should we interpret it metaphorically, or does he mean it in a more literal sense?

Do you have an exact text reference?

If he will not be satisfied with truth in the form of tautology, that is to say, if he will not be content with empty husks, then he will always exchange truths for illusions. What is a word? It is the copy in sound of a nerve stimulus. But the further inference from the nerve stimulus to a cause outside of us is already the result of a false and unjustifiable application of the principle of sufficient reason. (it is available in pdfcorner.com)

Title: On Truth and Lies in a Nonmoral Sense- Nietzsche
